# База данных Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать базу данных для discord.py бота. По типу он вступает на сервер Дискорд и в файл записывает в .json файл ID сервера,ID пользователей и ID всех каналов. Получается потом пользователь хочет чтобы он писал приветствие в определенном канале и от него требуется только введение сказать ID данного канала пример он пишет !setting и бот даёт список что может сделать, пользователь выбирает цифру 1 и ID канала,в этот момент бот смотрит в .json файле a: сервер,b:группу,c:канал, если такой есть то всё, бот будет там писать приветствие и так далее со всеми командами

Comment: Посмотрите https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro, возможно это вам поможет

Comment: за 10минут поиска нашел пару интересных деталей, но то что мне было нужно не нашёл :(

Comment: искал, искал....Не нашел(((